# Library for parsing scientific PDS files?

Tags: software-recommendations, file-formats, topography

Does a library exist for parsing the PDS files that scientific planetary data gets shipped as?

For example, here's a link to to the lunar topographic data from the Lunar Reconnaisance spacecraft (it's huge):

http://wms.lroc.asu.edu/lroc/global_product/256_ppd_DEM

I've seen the same format used elsewhere (for example, similar data from the Japanese Kaguya spacecraft).

Previously I've written custom parsers to massage the data into something I can actually use, but this is getting a bit complicated --- the LROC dataset has tiles of two different types of projection. What I'd really like is a library that I can just throw the PDS files at and say 'what is the data point for lat Y lon X' and have it give me an answer. Does such a thing exist?

Comment: I did actually write my own. It's not particularly sophisticated and I'm sure there are subtle (and not-so-subtle) problems with the interpolation, but it might still be useful. Look for the three `pds*.cc` files here: https://github.com/davidgiven/flooded-moon/tree/trunk/terrainmaker I used this to produce the pictures here: http://cowlark.com/flooded-moon/

Comment: Wow, way to respond such a long time later! Thanks! Looks helpful. Unfortunately I currently code in C# and have never programmed in C++. A lot looks familiar but then there are pieces that I definitely don't recognize. Hopefully after doing some research I'll be able to translate.